# Removing LP from Uniswap/Pancake using seth and removeLiquidityWithPermit(). How is the correct hash for the permission signing calculated?

Tags: solidity, web3js, signature, uniswap, pancakeswap

I'm trying to figure out how I can remove LPs from Uniswap/Pancakeswap using the function

```
  removeLiquidityWithPermit(address tokenA, address tokenB, uint256 liquidity, uint256 amountAMin, uint256 amountBMin, address to, uint256 deadline, bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s)
```

I want to do this on the command line so I'm using `seth`.
I managed so far the deposit, but now I'm facing an issue with the signing.
My major problem is how to calculate and obtain the values of `uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s`.

Uniswap function that checks the permission:

```
  function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external {
    require(deadline >= block.timestamp, 'UniswapV2: EXPIRED');
    bytes32 digest = keccak256(
        abi.encodePacked(
            '\x19\x01',
            DOMAIN_SEPARATOR,
            keccak256(abi.encode(PERMIT_TYPEHASH, owner, spender, value, nonces[owner]++, deadline))
        )
    );
    address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
    require(recoveredAddress != address(0) && recoveredAddress == owner, 'UniswapV2: INVALID_SIGNATURE');
    _approve(owner, spender, value);
}
```

I can't still figure out *what* and *how* to encode to get the right values.

I'm adding more code and experiments, I'm using that code in node to generate the hash that needs to be signed via `seth sign` later on, which is separated into `v, r, s` and attached to the send. Testing on BSC testnet and PancakeSwap

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');

const PERMIT_TYPEHASH = '0x6e71edae12b1b97f4d1f60370fef10105fa2faae0126114a169c64845d6126c9'; //is taken from the Pancake Testnet contract, 
const DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = '0x...'; // using the one assigned to the LPs from the LPs contract field!
const x19 = '\x19\x01';

//function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s)
var owner = '0x...'; // This is my address that is executing the send and also the owner of the LPs
var spender = '0x6725F303b657a9451d8BA641348b6761A6CC7a17' //Pancake swap
var value = '0'; //same like the submitted later on value
var nonce = '23'; // same like in the later on transaction containing the hashes
var deadline = '9632157400'; // same like in the later on submission with seth

var x = web3.utils.keccak256(web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['bytes32', 'address', 'address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256'],[PERMIT_TYPEHASH, owner, spender, value, nonce, deadline]));

var y = web3.utils.keccak256(web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['string','bytes32','bytes32'], [x19, DOMAIN_SEPARATOR, x]));

console.log(y) // this then gets signed with seth sign with the key form the sender.
```

Still I'm getting `Fail with error 'Pancake: INVALID_SIGNATURE'`. Am I doing something wrong here? Where should I look for a solution?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you get any answer ? i've faced same situation here right now :(
I've try re-deploy severals time but still doesn't work

Comment: @PromsurinPhutthammawong unfortunately not, haven't found a solution to that so far.

Comment: Did you fix this? I am also interested.

Comment: No, still no solution for me. Looking forward if you have found one!

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution

Comment: Main issue is changing name or symbol, make sure is "name" in solidity and "/views/RemoveLiquidty/index.tsx domain name. It must be same

Comment: @NizomjonHajiev sorry but I don't understand what you are talking about and how this is related to the question?

Comment: @bleedr I had similar issue while forking pancakeswap in testnet. We need to change "CAKE LPs" to our "XXX LPs". that time we got 'Fail with error 'Pancake: INVALID_SIGNATURE'  such issue.

Comment: @NizomjonHajiev ok, now I understand what you mean. I haven't forked it, I'm using already an available (and working) one on the testnet. I don't know the correct way to calculate the signature. Please check especially the variables and the formation of the hash, and let me know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and finally I solved it. When removing liquidity, the uniswap-interface  will request the wallet for signature. Do remember to change the token name sent to the wallet, which is in the uniswap-interface.
in my case ,it is in the file:uniswap-interface/src/pages/RemoveLiquidity/index.tsx,
and in the function onAttemptToApprove().
async function onAttemptToApprove() {
if (!pairContract || !pair || !library) throw new Error('missing dependencies')
const liquidityAmount = parsedAmounts[Field.LIQUIDITY]
if (!liquidityAmount) throw new Error('missing liquidity amount')
// try to gather a signature for permission
const nonce = await pairContract.nonces(account)

```
const deadlineForSignature: number = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000) + deadline

const EIP712Domain = [
  { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' }
]
const domain = {
  **name: 'iUniswap V2',**must be same as UniswapV2ERC20.sol
  version: '1',
  chainId: chainId,
  verifyingContract: pair.liquidityToken.address
}
```